# Expected number of King+Queen pairs

Tags: probability

Suppose we cut a 36-card deck into six piles of six cards each. How many marriages (King and Queen of the same suit in the same pile) do we expect to have?
It looks to me that the probability of marriage is $5/35 = 1/7$ and the expected number of marriages is $4/7$. Is this seems right?

Comment: I'm used to 52 card decks. What is the composition of a 36 card one?

Comment: Russian 36-card deck includes 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation is correct. For $i=\spadesuit,\heartsuit, \diamondsuit, \clubsuit$ let $X_i=1$ if the Queen and King of that suit end up in the same group of $6$, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $Y=\sum X_i$ is the number of marriages, and $E(Y)=\sum E(X_i)$.

Let us find the probability that the Queen and King of $\spadesuit$ end up in the same group of $6$. Whichever bunch the Queen of $\spadesuit$ ends up in,  the probability the King of $\spadesuit$ ends up in the same bunch is $\frac{5}{35}$.

Thus $E(X_\spadesuit)=\frac{5}{35}$. Multiply by $4$ to get $E(Y)$.